# Problems with a Radeon HD 5450 card on Ubuntu Server

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I'm having a hardware/driver problem with my Radeon HD 5450 card. Very grateful if anyone could help!

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu Server. I've assembled a machine and installed "Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS". The installation went fine. But the system hanged at boot - and the monitor went to sleep. I found help online, saying it could be caused be an unsupported video card. And yes - when I add "nomodeset" at boot I get a login prompt.

I did a "jockey-text --list", and found that the supported Ubuntu-driver was "fglrx". I installed that with apt-get.

I thought that would solve it, but it didn't. Now, when I boot without "nomodeset", I get a blank screen. The monitor doesn't go to sleep, but nothing is shown no matter what I do. The system is up, though - I can ping it and do a Alt+PrntScr R-S-E-I-N-U-B-reset. If I boot with "nomodeset" and then do a "startx" manually, I get the same blank screen.

Any ideas? The "fglrx"-driver should word fine with my card. (The card was released 2010, the driver is from 2012.) I looked at the Ubuntu wiki at "http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide", and tested generating a new xorg.conf file and a couple of other things. But I'd rather not hassle with installing drivers manually (downloading drivers from amd.com and building packages from ZIP-files) - I'm not that experienced...

Comment: Radeon HD 5450 is a pcie x16 card, and I am not quite sure what it's going to do on a server. Why not remove fglrx, pull out the card, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - you're right, mikewhatever! I thought I needed some sort of (simple) video card, but there actually is a simple one on the mother board. Removed the card and the fqlrx-driver and used the on-board card instead. Problem solved. Thanks! :-)